# Organizing the content of Euclidean geometry with pictorial mind maps

Tags: geometry, soft-question, euclidean-geometry, big-list

There is an idea that has been on my mind for a while, and I would like to share it so that it turns into a snowball. Perhaps it will be useful and attractive to engineering enthusiasts. I ask you to help me develop this model that I am thinking of...

Most geometric theorems are proven by putting several theorems together, but there are one or two theorems that represent the core idea of ​​the proof.

If you know the basic theorem you will use to do your proof, you still have to do some work to arrive at the proof, even though the basic step has already been done; Making a very large mind map would be impractical, but small mind maps can be made to express some conclusions

A lot of written mind maps can be done, but I think it would be fun and useful for geometry enthusiasts to have pictorial mind maps so they can guess a good visualization of the proof.

I think that pictorial mind maps are an excellent idea for engineering, as the engineering student has a good connection between the engineering content, and engineering mind maps still carry some challenge as they require work to complete the proof.

Most geometry enthusiasts can understand the statements and requirements of the theorem just from the picture, which is why Arseny Akopyan's book is so popular

I'll post some examples of mind maps I like and I hope my list of answers will expand...

[image]

The ground truth in the previous map is the one shown in the upper image; It may be intuitive, and the arrows point to conclusions, not entirely trivial

It is worth noting that the details of the proof need to be done; This is different from what is known as proof without words; If I wanted to turn the proof of the theorem on the right into a proof without words, it would be something like this:

[image]

This makes these mental diagrams a narrative of the theorem(s) that can be used in proof; But it still carries the challenge of actually doing this proof

Let's take a second example

[image]

If an engineering theorem can be used to prove theorems and perform geometric constructions, a ruler and compass can be placed next to the geometric construction to distinguish it, as in the previous picture.

[image]

It can be done the other way around, with one conclusion and many different ways to reach it.

[image]

It may be possible to reach one conclusion in many different ways

[image]

Double arrows can be used if the inference can be made in both directions, as is the case, for example, with the previous image.

However, there must be a well-understood stereotype for both the premises and the conclusions involved in mind maps of this type.

I would be happy to expand my list with more mind maps. Are there any fans of this idea?

Edit: What I'm looking for in this particular question is more examples of geometry mental diagrams like mine, in which each arrow points to an actual geometric proof

Comment: I am curious to know the person who proposes to close such an open and interesting question.

Comment: You address a very fundamental question, but a little too huge... First of all, due to the "duality" (in a wide sense of the word) between the "Geometrical/Pictorial world" and the "Algebraic World", your intended "pictorial mind map" as you call it, should be in two **separate** "sets" : one set for a (structured ?) "pictorial catalogue" and one set for the "algebraic apparatus" (in a wide sense of the word "algebraic" : not necessarily reduced to "formulas") with many "way-and-back" arrows between these sets. The pictorial part should inherit partly its structure from the alg. part.

Comment: Other things 1) Attempt to attach keywords (say up to 6 or 7 keywords) to each figure : in this way their relative distances should be inversely proportional to the number of common keywords... 2) The examples you show in Geometry are *figures* and the examples you show in Algebra are *formulas* ; but Geometry cannot be reduced to figures just as Algebra cannot be reduced to formulas, even if you group figures and formulas by relative affinity. Figures and formulas can be considered as base bricks. Your "mind map" should incorporate more abstract relationships dealing for example with methods.

Comment: Yes, of course, geometry or algebra cannot be reduced in this way, but anyone who wants to fill in the details can try on his own to do the proof; Making these images really took effort and time, starting with making each proof Individually, to identify logical connections, to find appropriate stereotypes, and in general, the idea is still taking shape. Thanks for the advice. @Jeanmarie

Comment: I like your "mind map" or visualization concept. That's what geometers do most of the time. Even that applies to the way  equations are written/ structured. But your name is difficult for me to mind map :), as most of the time we are accustomed to English .

Comment: @زكرياحسناوي you put a lot of effort in there. It is indeed unfortunate that it got closed.

Comment: I have voted to (re)close. Exposition of one's ideas, *without* a mathematical question, does not make an appropriate post on this site.

Comment: @Lee Mosher See the last "Edit: What I'm looking for in this particular question is more examples of geometry mental diagrams like mine, in which each arrow points to an actual geometric proof" Isn't it a question of the kind associated to the tag **"big-list"** which is in the list of tags ? Besides, the author of the question has been, these last months, a very original contributor.

Comment: @Lee Mosher: The OP has been honest with his logic behind the synthetic thought process through mental imagery.. He was successful in expressing a good part of the premises out of his logic . He needs support when he is unable to bring together into a ready make cookie question. Some patience when he is gathering his new original  thoughts is needed, a hurried closure of the topic may even look like crushing early research enthusiasm.

Answer (score 1):

Here I am adding an answer to the question to include another skill that can be used in mental diagrams, and perhaps I will expand the answer later with more mental diagrams...

[image]

The picture shows four ways to prove that the diameter of a circle is its longest chord

It can be noted that I sometimes put two theorems in one box to indicate that one proof uses these two theorems to arrive at the conclusion.

[image]

In the previous picture there are three inferences that can be proven using the triangle inequality

[image]

In the previous picture, five conclusions appear from the fact that the sum of the measures of two opposite angles in a cyclic quadrilateral equals 180°

[image]

In the previous picture, four conclusions appear regarding the fact that the tangents to the circle drawn from a point outside it are equal

Comment: Do you have an email address in order we can have direct exchanges ?

Comment: alrootsy101@gmail.com  @jeanMarie

Comment: @زكريا حسناوي:  Consider one particular or *specific example* only. Can you please state 1) What data is given? 2) What is the related pictorial support given? 3) What is required to be proven? 4) Then, *and then only* can we perhaps supply any  blanks that need to be filled up in the complete proof. Your question should contain 1)+2)+3) in order to be completely clear. That is how it appears to me your vague question got closed, and we could not help you with 4).

Comment: I have the complete actual proof of the schemes I proposed. I am not looking for someone who can prove the theories mentioned in the schemes. I am looking for more similar schemes. @Narasimham

Comment: Trying to understand if there are two things you wish to say: 1) Multiple ways to arrive at a single common result using contributing mental maps ( MM) *or* 2) its converse .. A single common premise to prove multiple results illustrated by MM ?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, as @Jean-Marie said, some mental diagrams should include information about the methods used in proof, which may not be obvious, so I suggest using stereotypes of common proof patterns, here are some examples...

Retrograde thinking:
[image]

Pigeon principle:
[image]

The principle of inclusion and exclusion:
[image]

Cavalieri principle:
[image]

The principle of infinite descent:
[image]

Mathematical induction:
[image]

Carpet principle:
[image]

Telescope series:
[image]

Proof by contradiction:
[image]

Counting in two ways:
[image]